# how to call name onkey up using ajax?

Tags: php, json, ajax, ajax4jsf

i am new to ajax. I want to get name from the database according to onkey up but i am getting this error in console "Invalid left-hand side in assignment". and when i type its showing "showname function is not defined".?
    This is my code.
    
    Search:

```
This is myscript
function showname(d) {
        var xhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
           }
          };
          xhttp.open("POST", "ajax2.php?name"=+d, true);
          xhttp.send();
    }
this ajax2.php code

$name = $_GET["name"];
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "customername");
$conn = $db->query("select customerName from customers like '".$name."%'");
$fetch = $conn->fetch_array();

?>
<?php foreach ($fetch as $key => $value) :?>
    <p><?php echo $value ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Better option would be to use jQuery auto-complete with remote data source.  https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: @AlokPatel why exactly would that be a better option?

Comment: @Shomz because it handle the user input properly, like only sending server request when user pauses writing in input field.

Comment: @AlokPatel I meant, it's not that hard to implement that on your own with the upsides of not using jQuery+jQueryUI... and it's a great practice for someone learning AJAX.

Comment: @Shomz Yeah if someone is learning AJAX, then its better to implement it on own. Otherwise no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: OR if you don't want to use jQuery ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xhttp.open("POST", "ajax2.php?name"=+d, true);

I think you got a typo there, put the = into the quote marks.

```
xhttp.open("POST", "ajax2.php?name=" + d, true);
```

Comment: It's working fine but it showing this error message mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource. but php code is correct

Comment: Check the error with mysql_error, it typically points you to the right location.

Comment: why some people check the value is comming using server or not using network console.

Comment: $conn = $db->query("select customerName from customers like '".$name."%'");

I just read your SQL query. It's wrong, it should be SELECT customerName FROM customers WHERE customerName LIKE '%$name%';